# pass date from clojure server to cljs frontend via transit format

Tags: mysql, jdbc, clojure, clojurescript, transit

A clojure server reads a datetime column from a mysql database. By using jdbc this action usually returns an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp`

I'm bringing this data to a frontend via the `transit` format. One could coerce the date to a timestamp and parse it on the frontend for further processing for e.g. the library cljs-time. Is this the way to go or is there another more convenient approach?

Comment: If you're using JDBC you should be able to convert it automatically to a java.until.Date (or other class of your choosing) at query time, would that solve your problem?

Comment: oh, I see now. java.util.Date is a transit type. good point. But to what would that be coerced at the client side?

Comment: last question is answered. when using java.util.Date, it will become an js/Date instance at the frontend. However, if someonw knows a concise way to receive java.util.Date from a jdbc / honeysql query, I'd still be keen to hear that.

Comment: not publishing it as an answer, but all you have to do is implement the IResultSetReadColumn (https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/IResultSetReadColumn) protocol on Timestamp. There's an example in Luminus.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the default type mappings in transit-cljs [here](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-cljs#default-type-mapping). By default Transit `time` values are mapped to JavaScript `Date`s. I much prefer to have the Dates mapped to `goog.Date.UtcDateTime`. There's [docs](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2015/9/10/extending-transit) on extending Transit Read and Write handlers, but here's what we use:

```
(def transit-readers
  {:handlers
   {"m" (transit/read-handler (fn [s] (UtcDateTime.fromTimestamp s)))
    "u" uuid}})

(def transit-writers
  {:handlers
   {UtcDateTime (transit/write-handler
                  (constantly "m")
                  (fn [v] (.getTime v))
                  (fn [v] (str (.getTime v))))}})
```